# Login on Website to external Portal

Tags: java, php, mysql, authentication

I have a website named www.example.com and I want a login form there inside a modal where a user can login and once he clicked the submit button, he will be logged in at www.test.com and also automatically forwarded to www.test.com!

I looked for some include functions but I am not sure how to solve that issue? Does anyone has an idea or a link to a tutorial so that I can see how this may work?

Please let me know if you need some additional information.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: is `www.test.com`  yours?

Comment: Yes! Both projects are mine!

Answer (score 1):

You could bring a login form from test.com into an iframe in example.com

```
<iframe src="http://www.test.com/login_form.php"></iframe>
```

your form, on test.com, should have the target set to "_top".

Then if login successful you are in www.test.com.

Else... you can redirect back to exemplo.com

Comment: Hmm..I already tried to solve it with an iFrame. Problem is that if I include the login page from www.test.com with an iFrame to the Modal on www.example.com than after a successfull login I stay inside the iFrame, therefore inside the modal window. This is not what I want.

Comment: Did you set the form target to "_top" ?

It should work

It would redirect to the parent frame (the window)

Comment: Yes I set it to target="_top" but I am still inside my modal once I am logged in!

Comment: So you can't use that. :(   
Then... I got that both domains are yours...   Are they both in the same server too? If so you could overide PHP's session handler with a custom one... take a look in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490875/how-to-manage-a-single-php5-session-on-multiple-apache-servers

Comment: Sorry... The idea being share the session data among the 2 sites

Comment: Just to make sure... in your form, within the iframe, were action set like: `action="/index.php"` or `action="http://www.test.com/index.php"` ?

Comment: YES action is set like that!