# send from JS to PHP securely from another server

Tags: javascript, php

i want to send information from JS on my domain to .php file in another domain securely and i want the .php to only accpet things coming from the specified domains .

This is Domain A

```
  $.ajax({
  POST: "https://domain-b.com/ant.php",
  data: mystring
})
```

This is Domain B

```
 <?php 
for ($i=0;$i<count($_POST);$i++){
       #send to DB code 
    }
    ?>
```

BTW both domain A and domain B are individual servers .
my understanding is because i am using `HTTPS` the data sent securely and encrypted , however i see that anyone can send information from anywhere to the .php domain . i want to prevent that .
i thought of inserting a code acts like a password between the two but as i insert it in the JS it will be visible to anyone , so no use for it .

Comment: Use an `IP whitelist` to verify the request comes from domain a?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using https will encrypt the data.

To check where the request claims to have originated from, you can check `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`  This can be spoofed however, and isn't reliable.

I would use a PHP session. Server A sets the session ID. Server B can then read the session ID from the request to verify that the user came from server A. It's possible for multiple servers to share the session data. See [How to manage a single PHP5 session on multiple apache servers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490875/how-to-manage-a-single-php5-session-on-multiple-apache-servers)

Answer (score 0):

As you are sending the post request from your server. Try sending a secret key in your data. and run the DB code only if the secret key matches.

```
<?php $_SESSION['key'] = md5(uniqid());
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['key']; ?>" name="key">
```

A new secret key is generated everytime a user refreshes the page. and it will be different from user to user.

```
$.ajax({
POST: "https://domain-b.com/ant.php",
 Data: mystring // contains secret key
})
```

php server

```
<?php 
$Key //your secret key
if($_SESSION['key'] == key in form data){
  for ($i=0;$i<count($_POST);$i++){
   #send to DB code 
  }
}
?>
```

If I understood the question correctly. this should be helpful :)

Comment: the secret key is shown to every one since it's in JS . 
i mean i could do 
`var Scrtkey='12312312313'; 
mystring = mystring+'scrt'+Scrtkey ;`
and then everyone sees it

Comment: Are you posting form data?

Comment: Yes , but it doesn't contain passwords .

Comment: then what you are looking for is solution for CSRF.

Comment: Will , I think there's a chance here . But if I attached the secret key generated by php to JS again it would be visible for it to work it must be sent from php to php only , if you have and idea please explain

Comment: It doesn't matter even if the user is able to see it. cause it changes everytime the page loads and different for each user browsing your webpage.

Comment: so i need to be sharing sessions between the two servers. 
because as you might have noticed in my question the JS on a server and the PHP on another . 
The PHP should act as an API . 
This is helpful in case they were all on the same server .