# Session alive across subdomains on different servers

Tags: php, session, keep-alive

I have two subdomains:
sub1.domain.tld and sub2.domain.tld

When I use session_start(); session cookie is set on both subdomains, because of:
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.domain.tld', true, true);

The problem is, that each subdomains refer to another server. When user works on sub1.domain.tld and after some certain time goes to sub2.domain.tld, session data may by deleted because there is no request to server sub2.domain.tld.

What is the best way to solve it? When User makes request to sub1.domain.tld so the server sub2.domain.tld is requested too, in order to keep session data alive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transfer session across server in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428032/transfer-session-across-server-in-php)

Comment: You can share session via database...