# Multiple PHP Web Servers to Share a Single Redis Server for User Sessions

Tags: php, redis, session-cookies, session-state, stateless-session

I have 2 web servers running PHP and Nginx... And I have 1 Redis Server. I want the web servers to use the Redis database for user login data. This will allow me to scale out the web servers without forcing logged-in users to re-authenticate if/when they hit a new server.

Both PHP/Nginx servers are using Redis for session handling, and they both point to the same Redis database. When I visit either site in my browser it generates a session token and stores it in Redis (creating two Redis keys total).... **But what I want is to create a new session when I visit Site #1, store the session in Redis, and have Site #2 recognize me when I visit because it queries Redis (so only one Redis key total).**

All 3 of my servers are in AWS, in the same VPC. I'm using internal IP addresses for communication b/w the web servers and Redis (so there is some amount of trust b/w the machines).

I'm obviously missing something here, and it might be the load balancer (which I will implement). But I was attempting to develop a Redis-sharing design with the minimal number of components. Also, I'm not entirely sure the load balancer helps w/ this issue.

Here are the relevant portions of code:

***PHP/Nginx Servers: (x2)***

**(1) /etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini**

```
session.save_handler = redis
session.save_path = "tcp://10.xxx.xx.xxx:6379" // both web servers point to the same Redis IP address
```

**(2) /var/www/html/test.php**

```
<?php 

ini_set('session.save_handler', 'redis'); // redundant; including for completeness
ini_set('session.save_path', 'tcp://10.xxx.xx.xxx:6379'); // redundant; including for completeness

session_name('FOOBAR');
session_start();
echo nl2br(
    '<pre>' . session_save_path() . '</pre>' . PHP_EOL
);

echo nl2br(
    'Running PHP version: ' . phpversion() . PHP_EOL
);

if (!array_key_exists('visit', $_SESSION)) {
    $_SESSION['visit'] = 0;
}
$_SESSION['visit']++;

echo nl2br(
    'You have been here ' . $_SESSION['visit'] . ' times.'
);
```

***Redis Server: (x1)***

**(3) /etc/redis/redis.conf**

```
bind 0.0.0.0
```

When I hit the *test.php* page for both sites, they successfully generate and store their own session in the Redis database. And they correctly increment their respective session token... But I want these web servers to share the Redis session data b/w them, so they "remember" all logged-in users (even if it's the user's first time hitting a given web server).

Thanks!

---

**EDIT:** I also attempted to manually query Redis for logged-in user data. This yielded similar results to *test.php* above. Each website ended up creating and managing its own session token.

***PHP/Nginx Servers: (x2)***

**(4) /var/www/html/redis-check.php**

```
<?php

   $cookie = "PHPREDIS_SESSION:" . $_COOKIE['FOOBAR'];

   // Connecting to Redis server on localhost 
   $redis = new Redis(); 
   $redis->connect('10.xxx.xx.xxx', 6379); 
   echo "Connection to server sucessfully";
   echo '<br />';

   // Check if cookie value exists in Redis 
   $seenuser = $redis->get($cookie);

   if( !empty($seenuser) )
   {
      echo 'Hello, old friend!<br />';
      echo '<br />';
      echo 'Cookie Value: ' . $cookie;
      echo '<br />';
      echo 'Session Value: ' . $seenuser;
   }
   else
   {
      // This is a new user, so create a new session
      ini_set('session.save_handler', 'redis'); // redundant; including for completeness
      ini_set('session.save_path', 'tcp://10.xxx.xx.xxx:6379'); // redundant; including for completeness
      session_name('FOOBAR');
      session_start();

      if (!array_key_exists('visit', $_SESSION))
      {
          $_SESSION['visit'] = 0;
      }
      $_SESSION['visit']++;

      $cookie = "PHPREDIS_SESSION:" . $_COOKIE['FOOBAR'];
      $seenuser = $redis->get($cookie);

      echo 'New Login<br />';
      echo '<br />';
      echo 'Cookie Value: ' . $cookie;
      echo '<br />';
      echo 'Session Value: ' . $seenuser;
   }
```

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/a/4428094/1213708 may give some hints (not something I've tried though)

Comment: [This will be helpful for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342378/cross-domain-login-how-to-login-a-user-automatically-when-transferred-from-one#answer-342498)

Comment: Thank you both! I will definitely check these out.

Comment: One thing could be worth trying out is to log into the redis server and query the keys being created.  This can show if a prefix is being used (it's also good to learn out how to check cache data as well).

Comment: Yeah, I had the same exact thought. It looks like the prefix is "PHPREDIS_SESSION:" (no quotes). And I was able to run GET commands using the values from that redis-check.php page. But again, there would be two Redis keys, one for each site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Looks like my issue was due to missing a load balancer.** I put HAProxy in front of my two web servers, pointed to HAProxy's address in the broswer, and the web servers immediately began sharing the session data stored in Redis. I guess they're both using the HAProxy address. And my browser (Chrome) shows only a single cookie for the HAProxy address (which is what I want)... When I bypass HAProxy and point to the web servers directly in the browser they generate their own session token (which is bad for this scenario).

**So here are the relevant code sections** ***(you can disregard what's in my OP):***

***PHP/Nginx Servers: (x2)***

**(1) /etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini**

```
session.save_handler = redis
session.save_path = "tcp://10.xxx.xx.xxx:6379" // both web servers point to the same Redis IP address
```

**(2) /var/www/html/test.php**

```
<?php

session_name('FOOBAR');
session_start();

echo 'IP Address: ' . getHostByName(getHostName());
echo '<br />';
echo '*******************************************************************************';
echo '<br />';

if (!array_key_exists('visit', $_SESSION))
{

    $_SESSION['visit'] = 0;

    echo 'Hello, new friend!';
    echo '<br />';
}
else
{

    echo 'Glad you are still with us!!';
    echo '<br />';
}

$_SESSION['visit']++;

echo 'You have been here ' . $_SESSION['visit'] . ' times.';
```

***Redis Server: (x1)***

**(3) /etc/redis/redis.conf**

```
bind 0.0.0.0
```

***HA Server: (x1)***

**(4) /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg**

```
frontend proxy_in
    bind *:80
    default_backend web_farm

backend web_farm
    balance roundrobin
    mode http
    server web1 10.xxx.xx.111:80 check  # web server 1
    server web2 10.xxx.xx.222:80 check  # web server 2
```

***PHP/Nginx Servers: (x2)***

**/var/www/html/redis-check.php**

```
Ignore this file. The revised test.php file is all that is needed.
```

Nigel and Saad, thank you for the links! It's ***always*** good to get a different POV on the problem.